# How to select each top 1 value from the table based on catgory_id in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How to select top 1 value from the table based on `category_id`?

I have a table like this. Please help me.

**Table 1**

```
ID Name category_id
-------------------
 1  A       1
 2  B       1
 3  c       1
 4  d       2
 5  e       2
 6  f       2
 7  g       3
 8  h       3
 9  i       3
```

How to get the below mentioned output from table 1?

```
ID Name category_id
--------------------
 1  A     1
 4  d     2
 7  g     3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([ID] int, [Name] varchar(1), [catgory_id] int)
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([ID], [Name], [catgory_id])
VALUES
    (1, 'A', 1),
    (2, 'B', 1),
    (3, 'c', 1),
    (4, 'd', 2),
    (5, 'e', 2),
    (6, 'f', 2),
    (7, 'g', 3),
    (8, 'h', 3),
    (9, 'i', 3)
;

SELECT [ID], [Name], [catgory_id]
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY [CATGORY_ID] ORDER BY [ID]
            ) AS RN
    FROM #TABLE1
    ) A
WHERE RN = 1
```

output

```
ID  Name    catgory_id
1   A         1
4   d         2
7   g         3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES [ID], [Name], [catgory_id]
FROM #Table1
ORDER BY 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY [CATGORY_ID] ORDER BY [ID] )
```